# What is the purpose of the INPUT chain in the nat table?

Tags: linux, iptables

What is the purpose of the `INPUT` chain in the `nat` table ?

The `PREROUTING` chain in the `nat` table is already doing the translation of the destination addresses (`DNAT`) of incoming packets ...as in what is commonly called "port forwarding".

The `nat:INPUT` and `nat:PREROUTING` chains seem redundant.

What would be the typical use of the `nat:INPUT` chain that cannot be accomplished in the `nat:PREROUTING` chain ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some NAT operation needs to be only done for the host itself where this netfilter is active, then performance can be better if the NAT rule is in the `INPUT` chain instead of `PREROUTING` chain.

This happens because only packets destined to the host are sent to the INPUT chains. If the rules is in PREROUTING chain, then all forwarded packets would need to be checked against the rule.

Also, there are scenarios where one does not want to apply any NAT to forwarded traffic, but only for traffic where the destination is the host itself.

Comment: OK, also please add this to your answer so others can benefit from it:  https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=c68cd6cc21eb329c47ff020ff7412bf58176984e